# Print a List of ints as a matrix

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of 9 integers and I want to print all elements from the list as a matrix 3,3. And I have to avoid unnecessary white space on the end of every line. 
Is it possible to use `String.Join` ?
Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
int[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

int[][] matrix = new int[input[0]][];

for (int i = 0; i < input[0]; i++)
{
    int[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

    matrix[i] = line;
}

List<int> arr = new List<int>(9);
List<int> arr1 = new List<int>(9);

arr = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 9).ToList();

//for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) sum[i%3, i/3] = 0;

for (int row = 0; row < input[0] - 2; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < input[1] - 2; col++)
    {
        arr1.Add(matrix[row][col]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row][col + 1]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row][col + 2]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 1][col]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 1][col + 1]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 1][col + 2]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 2][col]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 2][col + 1]);
        arr1.Add(matrix[row + 2][col + 2]);

        if (arr1.Sum() > arr.Sum())
        {
            arr = arr1.Select(a => a).ToList();
        }
        arr1.Clear();
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {arr.Sum()} ");

// print the list as a matrix
```

Comment: " Is it possible to use string.join" => Yes

Comment: "print all elements from the list as a matrix 3,3" where is your printing attempt? or did you mean you need to save the numbers in a 2D array of 3x3 ?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it! I want to print the List "arr" as a matrix at the end of the code

Comment: @MongZhu he is printing with `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: @PetkovAlexander It's clear you want a table format to print but can you add what you expect it to look like that would help alot

Comment: @MongZhu true but check the full code (you might have overlooked) he did put a comment at the end where he wants the table matrix to show.

Comment: @Franck ahh the comment at the end ?=! hehe, ok I did really oversee this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reconsider the accepted answer because the performance is poorly with many items.

It may be irrelevant for your current count of items but still hear my warning.

I ran the following code snippet:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < asd.Count; i +=3)
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", asd.Skip(i).Take(3)));
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

used a `StringBuilder` to remove the time relevant `Console.WriteLine();` for every item in the loop.

This approach takes `756,115ms` to complete, with 1,000,000 items.

Created the `asd` list like this:

```
var asd = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToList();
```

Every other answer given so far will perform way better.

The reason why the accepted solution performs this poorly is because of the `.Skip()` that is getting called inside the loop, it doesn't actually skip and go directly to this Position instead it again and again loops the list till it reaches this point.

My solution would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(asd.Select((x, i) => (i + 1) % 3 != 0 ? x + " " : x + Environment.NewLine)));
```

Which executes the same task in `8,610ms`

For completness:

- Wojtek's solution takes: `7,932ms`
- Nirmal Subedi' solution takes: `8,088ms`

Note:

Changed it so that it uses a `StringBuilder` to build the string and only output the string once to the console, instead of calling `Console.WriteLine()` in a loop

Here my complete test routine:

```
var asd = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToList();

var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(asd.Select((x, i) => (i + 1) % 3 != 0 ? x + " " : x + Environment.NewLine)));
sw1.Stop();

var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();

var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < asd.Count; i += 3)
    sb1.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", asd.Skip(i).Take(3)));
Console.WriteLine(sb1.ToString());

sw2.Stop();

var sw3 = new Stopwatch();
sw3.Start();

var sb2 = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;
string output = "";
foreach (int value in asd)
{
    counter++;
    if (counter % 3 == 0)
    {
        output += value;
        sb2.AppendLine(output);
        output = string.Empty;
    }
    else
        output += value + " ";
}
Console.WriteLine(sb2.ToString());
sw3.Stop();

var sw4 = new Stopwatch();
sw4.Start();

var sb3 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <asd.Count / 3; i++)
{
    int index = i * 3;
    sb3.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2}", asd[index], asd[index + 1], asd[index + 2]);
    sb3.AppendLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(sb3.ToString());
sw4.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("MySolution: " + sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Mong Zhu's Solution: " + sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Wojtek's Solution: " + sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Nirmal Subedi's Solution: " + sw4.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to improve more and get the insights about our solutions +1

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would print it using `String.Join`:

```
List<int> asd = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for (int i = 0; i < asd.Count; i +=3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",asd.Skip(i).Take(3)));
}
```

Explanation: Walk in steps of 3. Skip the amount of numbers equal to the stepsize and take 3 to combine a row of the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you meant?

```
    string output = string.Empty;
    List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    int counter = 0;
    foreach (int value in myList)
    {
        output += value.ToString();
        counter++;
        if (counter % 3 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            output = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Now You have your code pasted. Anyway, I created the sample to print the 3x3 matrix.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };


        for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
        {
            int index = i * 3;
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2}", numbers[index], numbers[index + 1], numbers[index + 2]);
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        Console.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```